# NexusJS Error: TypeError: Class constructor GraphQLNonNull cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: typescript, graphql, nexus-js

I was trying to learn nexus, but got a problems.

I created index.ts file with this code:

```
const User = objectType({
  name: 'User',
  definition(t) {
    t.id('id')
    t.string('name')
  }
})

export const schema = makeSchema({
  types: [User],
  outputs: {
    typegen: __dirname + '/generated/nexus.generated.ts',
    schema: __dirname + 'schema.graphql'
  }
})
```

Then I tryied to run script:

`ts-node-dev --transpily-only --no-notify index.ts`

And get an error in console:

```
TypeError: Class constructor GraphQLNonNull cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at SchemaBuilder.missingType (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1099:19)
    at SchemaBuilder.getOrBuildType (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1448:17)
    at /home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:794:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaBuilder.buildNexusTypes (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:782:38)
    at SchemaBuilder.getFinalTypeMap (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:835:10)
    at Object.makeSchemaInternal (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1684:92)
    at makeSchema (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/node_modules/nexus/src/makeSchema.ts:14:49)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zelleaz/Projects/mui/server/index.ts:11:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
```

I tried to reinstall nexus, but it doesn't work

Project files and dirs:

```
/node_modules
index.ts
package.json:
 dependencies: apollo-server, graphql, nexus
 dev-dep: ts-node-dev typescript
package-lock.js
```

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work with graphql package version 16+ 

I used graphql v 14.5.8 and it solved the problem.
nexus version is 1.1.0

Comment: nexus doesn't work with graphql 16+
Github pull-request with fixes or something:
https://github.com/graphql-nexus/nexus/pull/977

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading to graphql@^15.8.0 resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

NexusJS for this moment doesn't work with graphql 16+
So you must use older versions.
In my case 14.5.8 (from GitHub nexus example) workes correctly
There's pull-request with fixes for graphql 16+ version:
https://github.com/graphql-nexus/nexus/pull/977

Answer (score 1):

TypeError: Class constructor GraphQLNonNull cannot be invoked without
'**new**'

**Solution**:

name:{type:**new** GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},

age:{type:**new** GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)},

Answer (score 0):

They haven't put a stable release right now but the version nexus@1.2.0-next.17 seems to work fine for me atm ref https://github.com/graphql-nexus/nexus/pull/1017
It's not officially supported yet so you'll have to put in .env or env.local "PEER_DEPENDENCY_CHECK='false'" for now in order for it to disable this peer dependency check.
then you can have the latest graphql 16+

it's definitely saved me from having to a prisma migrate dev and prisma db push to remove type errors.

Hopefully they'll get a stable version 1.2.0 by Q1/Q2 2022 my guess